# select an option without reload page

Tags: jquery

i know, that my code is not well, but i tryed my best.

here is my code:

```
function submitForm() {
    document.getElementById("formElement").submit();
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var img = new Image();
    $(img).load(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#loader').removeClass('loading').append(this);
    $(this).fadeIn(800);
}).attr('src', '.chart.php?id=<? echo $sid; ?>&date=<? echo $order; ?>');
});

<div id="loader" class="loading"></div>

<select name="order" class="dropdown" onChange="submitForm()">
<option disabled selected> <? echo(CHOOSE); ?> </option>
<option value="./chart.php?id=<? echo $sid; ?>&date=d"> <? echo(CHOOSE_DAY); ?> </option>
<option value="./chart.php?id=<? echo $sid; ?>&date=m"> <? echo(CHOOSE_MONTH); ?> </option>
<option value="./chart.php?id=<? echo $sid; ?>&date=y"> <? echo(CHOOSE_YEAR); ?> </option>
</select>
```

my problem is, that i dont want to reload always the page if i use the select options.

i hope any can help me, thx for now^^

Comment: If you do not want to reload always onchange, then don't bind the onChange to submitForm. What condition are you looking for to submit?

Comment: Yep, confused here as well. When I order steak, they bring me a steak. How can I stop that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how to make "Ajax" with jQuery. You could start with : 
[5 Ways to Make Ajax Calls with jQuery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/)

Comment: i tryed already a different code like:

      $(".dropdown").change(function() {
            var src = $("option:selected", this).val();
            $("#loader").html(src ? "<img src='" + src + "'>" : "");
            });

and i change the values from options, delete the submit code.

but now the first img not display, just if i use select. maybe i have to use if val() == "" then show standard img? or something?

thx for help me^^

Answer (score 1):

On your `select` you are calling `onChange="submitForm()"`

Your `submitForm()` function submits the form.

If you wanted to submit the form via ajax, instead of by a standard form submit, which will always reload the page, then inside your `jQuery(document).ready(function($){})` call, you can use `$.post`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#formElement').submit(function(){
        $.post('url/to/post/to.php', $(this).serialize, function(data){
            // Some code to run on successful post
        });
        return false;
    });
})
```

This way, when your `submitForm()` function calls `.submit()`, the `return false;` blocks the page reload, but the `$.post()` still posts your data to whatever page is processing your form submits.

Comment: hi daybreaker, i cant make it work, your code. now i try it with ajax and still not really work. im to stupid, sorry guys.